# Public key cant be found in file Explorer

Tags: permissions, files

I have a school project and we are using ubuntu .
( im new to all this stuff just want to let u know :) )
for this project we had to create a public key ; shh keygen
I did all of it , got the key and all seemed well , when i went to the site that i had to upload this key too , i couldnt find it ...( , i made sure that i can see all hadden files on the Explorer,  but still no luck .)

I also cant open the file root in the ubuntu map ? It sais that i dont have permission and i should ask admin for permission .

Answer (score -1):

You seem to have generated ssh key pair successfully. You generate ssh key pair by running

```
    ssh-keygen
```

`ssh-keygen` prompts you to enter filename for saving generated key pairs. The default is `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa`.

- If you did not give filename with full path then keys was saved in your (then) current working directory.
- If you didn't gave any name then your ssh public key is `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. In this case run the following in terminal

```
    gedit $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub #open ssh public key in gedit
```

Or to locate `$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` in file manager `open file manager` -> `choose Home in left pane` -> `enter .ssh folder` -> `locate id_rsa.pub`

For most use cases, specially dealing with generating ssh key pairs you don't need root permissions. Btw what is "file root in ubuntu map"?

[0][generate ssh keys https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/configure-ssh-keygen](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/configure-ssh-keygen)

Comment: I would like to know why was this answer down voted. I will help me improve this answer and help me write future answers.

Answer (score -2):

to use root privileges you need `sudo` in front of each command, example: `sudo ssh-keygen`

- Open terminal and try `ls -a` to list all file -a option to list all files. You should see a file named `.ssh`.
- Then use `ls -a .ssh` to list all files withing the `.ssh` file, your public key is there with `.pub` extension.
- Open it with any text editor, vim or nano. For example `nano ./ssh/file_name.pub`, thats it.